# Read a Node inside another Node in XML with java

Tags: java, xml, object

I'm trying to read an XML file using java. The problem is that I don't know how should I read an object which is included inside another object. Here is the example.

```
<o1>
    <id>123</id>
    <name>abc</name>
    <o2>
        <o3>
            <name>xyz</name>
            <adr>somewhere</adr>
        </o3>
        <o3>
            <name>mno</name>
            <adr>anotherwhere</adr>
        </o3>
    </o2>
</o1>
```

I want to extract these data into my java program. This is an example of reading data but it is not useful for reading an object inside another one. 
The code is from [this url](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

```
File fXmlFile = new File("code.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("o1");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "node" with a "node"

Comment: explain a bit more. what is needed?

Comment: If I want to make a real example, consider we have a list of people where each person has a list of books that it has. How can we make a graph which represents the ownership of the books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of possible ways this might be achieved...

You could...

### Use a SAX parser

A [SAX parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html) would allow you to process the document AS it's been read.  This is really useful when the document might be too large to maintain in memory.

### Use a DOM parer

A [DOM parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/) generates (typically) a in memory representation of the document, which you can scan, search and if you want, manipulate.

#### And read the basic document structure

With a DOM model, you could start at the root node and do a recursive search of all the child nodes, process the content as you go.  This is similar to how a SAX parser would would work (conceptually)

#### Or use xPath

Or, if you just want search for and pick out certain content, you could use a `XPath`, which will allow you to query the document for content.

This is useful when you know what you want or you need to perform repeated searches over the document, for example, based on your example `code.xml`, the following...

```
try {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("code.xml"));
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression exp = xPath.compile("//name");
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {
        Node node = nl.item(index);
        Node parent = node.getParentNode();
        System.out.println("Parent: " + parent.getNodeName());
        System.out.println("    Name: " + node.getTextContent());
        
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Will output

```
Parent: o1
    Name: abc
Parent: o3
    Name: xyz
Parent: o3
    Name: mno
```

Have a look at [How XPath Works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) and [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) for more details...

Comment: I think using XPath is the appropriate solution to the problem I am working at, but the whole question may be solved by other parsers. Thanks.